# regex delete line which contains word and previous condition is true

Tags: regex

I would to delete only the intere line which contains word "DELESTAT" and only if block start with WSPRD2

block start with WSPRD2# (variable#) and finish with END

could you kindly help me.

```
WSPRD3#/TO/PATH/TASK5
 PRIORITY 60
NEEDS 1 MASTER#AAA0RTYU
NEEDS 1 MASTER#DELESTAT
NEEDS 1 MASTER#RAAA1JK

 FOLLOWS GET_INPUT

END

WSPRD2#/TO/PATH/TASK6
 PRIORITY 60
NEEDS 1 MASTER#AAA0RETU
NEEDS 1 MASTER#DELESTAT
NEEDS 1 MASTER#RAAACCC

 FOLLOWS GET_INPUT

END

WSPRD4#/TO/PATH/TASK8
 PRIORITY 60
NEEDS 1 MASTER#AAA0RETU
NEEDS 1 MASTER#DELESTAT
NEEDS 1 MASTER#RAAACCC

 FOLLOWS GET_INPUT

END
```

from this:

```
   WSPRD2#/TO/PATH/TASK6
    PRIORITY 60
   NEEDS 1 MASTER#AAA0RETU
   NEEDS 1 MASTER#DELESTAT
   NEEDS 1 MASTER#RAAACCC
   
    FOLLOWS GET_INPUT
   
   END
```

to this:

delete only the entire line which contains word "DELESTAT" and only if block start with WSPRD2#

```
   WSPRD2#/TO/PATH/TASK6
    PRIORITY 60
   NEEDS 1 MASTER#AAA0RETU
   NEEDS 1 MASTER#RAAACCC
   
    FOLLOWS GET_INPUT
   
   END
```

i try with this regex: https://regex101.com/r/OfMlqy/1

the problem is that it match all the lines in block from line WSPRD2 until line DELESTAT include.

```
(?s)^(WSPRD2.*?DELESTAT(?:.*?\n)*?)
```

```
WSPRD2#/TO/PATH/TASK6
 PRIORITY 60
NEEDS 1 MASTER#AAA0RETU
NEEDS 1 MASTER#DELESTAT
```

thanks.

Comment: Are you using PCRE like in your demo? If so, there is [`\K` available, which resets](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-php.html#K) the match-start. So you can match the lines starting from `WSPRD2` and *reset* before the line that contains `DELESTAT`, something like [this update of your demo](https://regex101.com/r/OfMlqy/3). It's unclear yet if you need to check for `END` too.

Comment: @bobblebubble i need to check END it was to make sure I had the whole block Your regex match is what I need without check END, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can attempt to match

```
^(WSPRD2\b.*\r?\n(?:(?!END\b).*\r?\n)*).*\bDELESTAT\b.*\r?\n
```

with the flag that causes `^` and `$` to anchor the beginning and end of a line, respectively.

If there is a match it is to be be replaced with the the contents of capture group 1 (`$` or `\1`, depending on the language).

This uses no advanced regex features so it should work with most regex engines.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/430Skw/1)

The expression can be broken down as follows.

```
^                      # match the beginning of a line
(                      # begin capture group 1
  WSPRD2\b             # match 'WSPRD2'
  .*\r?\n              # match remainder of the line  
  (?:                  # begin a non-capture group
    (?!                # begin negative lookahead
      END\b            # match 'END' at the beginning of the line
    )                  # end negative lookahead
    .*\r?\n            # match entire line
  )                    # end non-capture group
  *                    # exectute preceding non-capture group >= 0 times
)                      # end capture group 1
.*\bDELESTAT\b.*\r?\n  # match a line containing 'DELESTAT'
```

Comment: Cary Swoveland, thanks, works fine.